# Cannot connect to Flask-Eve API

Tags: python, api, flask, eve

I'm trying to use Eve to manipulate data on MongoDB.
I followed the Eve's official instruction to test the result, then failed.

**[Eve's official instruction for quick-start](http://docs.python-eve.org/en/stable/quickstart.html)**

touch 2 files in a same document as below

```py
#/run.py

from eve import Eve
app = Eve()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

```py
#/settings.py

DOMAIN = {'people': {}}
```

**Result**

Afterward I type `$ python run.py` to launch API in command line, and nothing happend.
It should tell me the address as the official instruction told.

```sh
#It should be like this
$ python run.py
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/

$ curl -i http://127.0.0.1:5000
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 82
Server: Eve/0.0.5-dev Werkzeug/0.8.3 Python/2.7.3
Date: Wed, 27 Mar 2013 16:06:44 GMT



#My situation
$ python run.py
 * nothing

$ curl -i http://127.0.0.1:5000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 5000: Connection refused
```

I really have no idea how to deal with it.

Comment: Have a look at your eve version and python version too ? It must not happened here, everything looks smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Try following way and see if it works

```
#/run.py

from eve import Eve
from flask_sslify import SSLify

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Eve()
    app.run()
```

I had the same issue. I installed **Flask-SSLify** and it worked.